# Implementing logging

Tags: java, logging

I was just wondering if following thing exists.

I have a TCP communicator which keeps communicating with thousands of devices.

Currently, the TCP communicator logs all the events in one log file.

Now, is it possible to log communication with every device in different files. The IMEI number of every device is different. So the logger will check if a file with name equal to the  IMEI number of the device exists. If the file exists, logger will start logging events of the device in that file, otherwise it will create a new file with IMEI as the file's name and start logging the events in that file.

(We are developing our application in Java.)

Comment: What logging utility are you using? `java.util.logging`? Or log4j, slf4j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch) is the future, and it's here!

Created as a successor of log4j and fully complaint with the slf4j framework, logback might be the easy (and clean) way to fulfill your need.

I'm not an expert but I guess that [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) might be the right answer. There should be a discriminator option for you. Maybe you can build your own discriminator, extend the SiftingAppender, or get some extra help from Janino library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: SiftingAppender is designed to handled exactly this type of situation. Just raise the question on the logback-user mailing list for further help.

Comment: @Gevorg & Ceki  Thanks for the answer. We have used SiftingAppender and it helped us to meet our requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing the logger yourself, there's nothing to stop you from doing this.
For example, give the log function as a parameter the number of the device you're currently communicating with, and implement it the way you described.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Apache log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/index.html), which I highly recommend, create a custom logging appender by extending [AppenderSkeleton](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html) and writing unique files for individual connections will be as simple as doing standard file I/O with a variable filename.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `java.util.logging`, look at the [`Handler` base class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html), if you are using log4j, look at [`Appender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html). In both cases, you need to somehow get the IMEI associated with the message, so the code writing the log message can pick the appropriate file.

There are two approaches to doing this.

First is to extend the log event class ([`LogRecord`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html) or [`LoggingEvent`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html) respectively). This would allow you to log using your event, which contains the IMEI. However, this does not account for logging performed by other libraries etc while performing the conversation with a device.

The other alternative is to use a ThreadLocal. Set the IMEI associated with a socket whenever you receive a message or are formulating message. Make sure that the logging happens in the same thread, and any queuing is done at the log handler/appender. Look for / ask questions about ThreadLocals if you are unfamiliar with this approach. I believe that Log4J's [`NDC`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html) and [`MDC`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) implements this sort of strategy, but I've not tried to do specialized processing of context at the appender.

Finally, be aware some operating systems will run out of file handles if you are indeed thinking of keeping "thousands" of log files open. Depending on just how many files, you may want to consider writing log messages (with IMEI) to a database, or doing some sort of LRU-based file closing. In the latter, you would basically not have file handles for log files that haven't been touched in a while.